# TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile cannot write to application directory on some devices

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-4.1-jelly-bean

My application synthesizes WAV files using Android TTS feature.

The resulting files are stored inside application directory /data/data/package_name/tts-cache/file_name.wav.

Basically it works but on some devices, like Samsung Galasy S2 (4.1.2) TTS service is unable to write to this folder and the application is hit with Permission Denied exception.

I would opt not to change the WAV folder to external store directory.
Is there anything I could do about it on 4.1.2.
I'm not sure if it is Samsung S2 or Android 4.1.2 bug / feature.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem on my rooted sprint galaxy s2 while it was working on my galaxy s3 and my asus fonepad. So it might be related to the device

I don't remember what was the message in the LogCat may be you can post the warning displayed while using synthetizeToFile (I remembered having more than just a Permission Denied but it may just be my imagination) it could help (I don't own my galaxy s2 anymore sadly).

Comment: There is nothing more than this related to TTS in the log file.